# Avoid loading the same script twice with rFSM library in LUA

Tags: lua, lua-5.1, lua-5.2

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

The following code is a minimal example that replicates a problem I am having. The rFSM library is used, which can be found here: https://github.com/kmarkus/rFSM

There are three lua scripts. The "main", called `runscript.lua`, which initializes and runs the state machine (SM) that needs to be run, called `mainTask.lua`, which in turn, uses an auxiliary state machine `subTask.lua`.

The code flow is the following. We start inside the state machine `mainTask.lua` and immediately enter the `Sim` composite state, and then the state `evaluate`. There, we are calling the function `evaluateData` which is inside `subTask.lua` and set the local variable `var` to `false`. After this function call, we go to `mainTask.lua` again, make a transition and end up inside `subTask.lua` again. There we print the value of `var`.

Again, schematically: `mainTask.lua` -> `subTask.lua` -> `mainTask.lua` -> `subTask.lua`.

We expect the value of `var` to be `false`. However, as you can see, inside `mainTask.lua`, we are loading the `subTask.lua` twice via `rfsm.load("subTask.lua"),`. This results in having two instances of the auxiliary SM, but I want to have one instead.

The `rfsm.load` function is

```
function load(file)
   local fsm = dofile(file)
   if not is_state(fsm) then
      error("rfsm.load: no valid rfsm in file '" .. tostring(file) .. "' found.")
   end
   return fsm
end
```

**CODE**

`runscript.lua`

```
-- Set lua path to location of rFSM library
package.path = "/home/anfr/rFSM-master/?.lua;./?.lua";
require 'rfsm';
print('[runscript.lua] Before rfsm.load("mainTask.lua")')
fsm_ = rfsm.load("mainTask.lua")
print('[runscript.lua] Before rfsm.init(fsm_)')
fsm = rfsm.init(fsm_);
print('[runscript.lua] Before rfsm.run(fsm)')
rfsm.run(fsm);
```

`mainTask.lua`

```
local var = true;

return rfsm.state{

  Sim = rfsm.composite_state
  {
    evaluate = rfsm.state {
      entry=function()
        var = false;
        if (evaluateData(var)) then
          rfsm.send_events(fsm, "internal_EvaluateDone")
        end
      end,
    },

    sub = rfsm.load("subTask.lua"),

    rfsm.trans { 
      src='initial', 
      tgt='evaluate',
      effect=function()
        print('[mainTask.lua] initial -> evaluate')
      end,
    },
  
    rfsm.trans { 
      src='evaluate', 
      tgt='sub',
      events={'internal_EvaluateDone'},
      effect=function()
        print('[mainTask.lua] evaluate -> sub with event "internal_EvaluateDone"')
      end,
    },
  }, -- end of Sim
  
  Seq = rfsm.composite_state
  {
    entry=function()
      print('Entry Seq')
    end,

    exit=function()
      print('Exit Seq')
    end,
 
    Running = rfsm.composite_state
    {
      entry=function()
        print('Entry Running')
      end,
  
      exit=function()
        print('Exit Running')
      end,

      --sub_2 = sub,
      sub_2 = rfsm.load("subTask.lua"),

      rfsm.trans { 
        src='initial', 
        tgt='sub_2',
        effect=function()
          print('[Seq composite state] initial -> sub_2')
        end,
      },

    },

    rfsm.trans { 
      src='initial', 
      tgt='Running',
      effect=function()
        print('[Seq composite state] initial -> Running')
      end,
    },
  
  }, -- end of Seq
  
  rfsm.trans { 
    src='initial', 
    tgt='Sim',
    effect=function()
      print('[mainTask.lua] initial -> Sim')
    end,
  },

};
```

`subTask.lua`

```
print("--- start of subTask.lua ---")
local var = true;

function evaluateData(value)
  print("[subTask.lua] var before setting in evaluateData is " .. tostring(var));
  var = value;
  print("[subTask.lua] var after setting in evaluateData is " .. tostring(var))
  return true
end

return rfsm.state {

  execute = rfsm.state {
    entry=function()
      print('[subTask.lua] var inside execute is ' .. tostring(var))
    end,
  },

  rfsm.trans {
    src='initial', 
    tgt='execute',
    effect=function()
      print('[subTask.lua] initial -> execute')
    end,
  },

},

print("---   end of subTask.lua ---")
```

**LOGS**

The following logs show that the second time we enter the auxiliary SM, we use the second instance where the value of `var` is `true` (we don't want this).

```
[runscript.lua] Before rfsm.load("mainTask.lua")
--- start of subTask.lua ---
---   end of subTask.lua ---
--- start of subTask.lua ---
---   end of subTask.lua ---
[runscript.lua] Before rfsm.init(fsm_)
[runscript.lua] Before rfsm.run(fsm)
[mainTask.lua] initial -> Sim
[mainTask.lua] initial -> evaluate
[subTask.lua] var before setting in evaluateData is true
[subTask.lua] var after setting in evaluateData is false
[mainTask.lua] evaluate -> sub with event "internal_EvaluateDone"
[subTask.lua] initial -> execute
[subTask.lua] var inside execute is true
```

**ATTEMPTS FOR A SOLUTION**

*Attempt 1*

This attempt actually works in my local example (not the real system) and uses the commented line
`sub_2 = sub`. So the idea was to to load the state machine once, and here simply refer to that. I am wondering if the different versions of LUA have an impact on this. Locally I have Lua 5.2, on system Lua 5.1.

**Edit**

This attempt stops working if I simply add another dummy state inside the `Seq` composite state. Also there is no dependence on Lua versions.

*Attempt 2*

Implement a second version of `load` and use `require` instead of `dofile`. Then use this function in those two places inside `mainTask.lua`.

```
function load2(file)
   local fileWithoutExtension = file:gsub("%.lua", "")
   print(fileWithoutExtension)
   local fsm = require(fileWithoutExtension)
   if not is_state(fsm) then
      error("rfsm.load: no valid rfsm in file '" .. tostring(file) .. "' found.")
   end
   return fsm
end
```

If I run this I get:

```
[runscript.lua] Before rfsm.load("mainTask.lua")
subTask
--- start of subTask.lua ---
---   end of subTask.lua ---
subTask
[runscript.lua] Before rfsm.init(fsm_)
lua: /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:483: bad argument #1 to 'find' (string expected, got table)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'find'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:483: in function '__resolve_path'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:511: in function '__resolve_src'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:551: in function 'func'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:272: in function 'f'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/utils.lua:246: in function 'map'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:268: in function '__mapfsm'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:275: in function 'f'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/utils.lua:246: in function 'map'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:268: in function '__mapfsm'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:275: in function 'f'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/utils.lua:246: in function 'map'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:268: in function '__mapfsm'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:283: in function 'mapfsm'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:554: in function 'resolve_trans'
    /home/anfr/rFSM-master/rfsm.lua:704: in function 'init'
    runscript.lua:9: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

I don't understand why I get a table instead of a string. Unfortunately one needs to navigate in the rFSM lib code to help, but I would appreciate any hints.

Ps: Making the variable `var` global inside `subTask.lua` will give the correct behaviour. However I am trying to avoid the unnecessary overhead of loading the same script two times.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if the different versions of LUA have an impact on this

All Lua versions have the same semantics of object references assignment.

---

> as you can see, inside mainTask.lua, we are loading the subTask.lua twice via rfsm.load("subTask.lua")

When you use `require` the same state object is returned.

---

> I don't understand why I get a table instead of a string

The function `resolve_trans(fsm)` converts `.src` fields of transitions from stings to objects (tables).
When you resolve the same transition object for the second time, the error is raised because `tr.src` field is expected to be a string.

Comment: In this line ```return utils.andt(mapfsm(__resolve_trans, fsm, is_trans))``` we are calling ```__resolve_trans``` which is  ```local function __resolve_trans(tr, parent) return __resolve_src(tr, parent) and __resolve_tgt(tr, parent) end ``` Where are we getting the ```tr``` and ```parent``` from?

Comment: parent = states, tr = element of states which is a transition

Comment: any recommendations and/or pointers on how I should modify the code?

Comment: `This results in having two instances of the auxiliary SM, but I want to have one instead.` - Why optimizing it?  Leave it as it is.  :-)